# Why does Jezus Leeft receive a lower list number than StemNL despite participating in a smaller number of constituencies?

Tags: election, netherlands

According to the [*Proces-verbaal geldigheid kandidatenlijsten*](https://www.kiesraad.nl/binaries/kiesraad/documenten/rapporten/2017/2/proces-verbaal-geldigheid-lijsten-kandidaten-en-lijstencombinaties/proces-verbaal-geldigheid-kandidatenlijsten/I4_PV+geldigheid+kandidatenlijsten+en+lijstnummering_TK2017.pdf) (PDF, 5.4 MB), page 707:

> Vervolgens zijn de overige kandidatenlijsten genummerd in de volgorde van het aantal kieskringen waarvoor de
>   lijst is ingeleverd.

Which means:

> *Next* [after the parties which received seats in the previous elections] *are numbered the other candidate lists, in the order of the number of constituencies for which a list was handed in.*

Looking at the list, the lists are numbered as follows:

24. Lokaal in de Kamer, 15 constituencies
25. JEZUS LEEFT, 7 constituencies
26. StemNL, 9 constituencies
27. MenS en Spirit / Basisinkomen Partij / V-R, 2 constituencies

There appears to be a contradiction between the explanation of how lists are numbered (descending order number of constituencies), and the order between lists 25 and 26.  Why did JEZUS LEEFT receive a lower list number than StemNL despite participating in fewer constituencies?

I thought there might be a clue in the difference between the number of constituencies for which a list was handed in, versus the number that was approved.  This does not explain the discrepancy: section five of the proces-verbaal (page 19 onward) describes rejected lists; Jezus Leeft handed in lists in 7 constituencies, all were approved; StemNL handed in lists in 20 constituencies, 11 were rejected, 9 were approved.  So the inconsistent list ordering does not relate to the number of constituencies prior to approval checking, either.

Comment: This might be a genuine error, as many lists were handed in shortly before the deadline, and publication was within hours. Apparently, StemNL didn't care enough to appeal. (I can't provide any link to support this, therefore I won't post it as an answer)

Comment: Kiesraad should give themselves some time between the deadline for handing in the lists and the publication of lists and list numbers…!

Comment: As there is a minimum time between publication and the elections, the only way to get more time for checking is to move the deadline back in time, reducing the time available to the parties to gather signatures. I'm glad the Kiesraad uses a pragmatic approach and is not as bureaucratic as it could be.